# Problem in extracting the result of a query

Tags: java, mysql

I just want to get two columns text and aid based on a condition and put the result in two arrays one for each column but only one column I'm able to extract as when I try to get the other as in the code below it gave me white page! When I remove one and leave the other it works whatever which column it only works in one only so what is the problem?

```
<%
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fci";
    String user = "root";
    String password = "root";
    Statement Stmt = null;
    ResultSet RS = null;
    Connection Con = null;

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); 
        Con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password); 
        Stmt = Con.createStatement();


       String queryString2 = " select aid,text from ans where qid=1" ;                
       RS = Stmt.executeQuery(queryString2);

      String[] answers = {"0","0","0"};
      String[] answers_id = {"0","0","0"};

      int count=0;
      while(RS.next())
       {

       answers[count++] = RS.getString("text");
       answers_id[count++]=RS.getString("aid");
        for(int i =0; i< 3 ; i++)
       {
           out.println(answers[i] );                  
           out.println(answers_id[i]);
       }
       Con.close();
       RS.close();

     } catch (Exception cnfe) {
        System.err.println("Exception: " + cnfe);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are double-incrementing `count` in your loop, resulting in an array index that is out of bounds. Change

```
answers[count++] = RS.getString("text");
answers_id[count++]=RS.getString("aid");
```

To

```
answers[count] = RS.getString("text");
answers_id[count++]=RS.getString("aid");
```

and that should solve your problem.